# Routing in Angular JS with Multiple Slashes (1.2.x)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angular-routing

I have injected ngRoute into my angular app, and routing works when paths are only one level deep, ie. only have a single slash.

in app.js:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/guestlist', {
      templateUrl: 'guestlist.html',
      controller: 'guestListCtrl'
    })
    .when('/event/apply', {
      templateUrl: 'apply-to-event.html',
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
    })
    .when('/event/confirmation', {
      templateUrl: 'apply-to-event-confirmation.html',
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
    })
    .when('/event', {
      templateUrl: 'event.html',
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

The routes that do not work are `/event/apply` and `/event/confirmation`, they just go straight to `/`. However, `/event` and `/guestlist`, for example, do work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated,

Comment: Can you make a plnkr? It seems that this should work .

Comment: Are you sure your controllers have correct names and your html files exist in given paths?

Comment: It does look like your 'apply' and 'confirmation' routes are using the same controllers as your main 'event' route... could that be the issue?

Comment: Josh Taylor, indeed I just tried to assign them different controllers and it works. Do you know why you can't share controllers between routes in Angular? I'm off to google it.

Comment: You can share controllers. Perhaps something is happening within the EventCtrl that redirects to root.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem similar to one i had a few years ago.
Try adding this to your meta  :

```
 <base href="/">
```

[source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)